# Open Third Party apps from my application

Tags: windows, blackberry, cross-platform

I am doing some research before developing my application. Just to give you a brief about what I intend to do is the following:

1. Develop a cross platform app (ios,android,blackberry,windows phone and pc)
2. This app will be linked to various third party apps (can be either installed or need to be installed).

I've already found some info how to open third party apps: ios and android. I am searching for other services (windows phone and blackberry) and could not find anything or I'm typing the wrong keywords in Google search.!!

For Iphone I found the following:

1. itms-apps://
2. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8&uo=4
3. Use the iTunes Link Maker at http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker to create a link to any app.

For Android:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher

Both the above are linking to App store and Play Store accordingly. How can I link to an already installed app if the app is installed.

Thanks

Comment: Windows Mobile != Windows Phone.

Comment: For me its the same. I just replaced it.

Comment: Can we answer this question when we don't know what you are using to develop this cross platform application?  Is there even a tool set that will let you develop once and work across all these platforms?

Comment: Yes Peter there are tools like for example HTML5,Xamarin,MoSync,tideSDK etc. Yes you can answer this question. Its all reseach I am not developing anything yet..

Answer (score 0):

### For Android ONLY

The Android ecosystem is based on [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). The only thing you need to know to launch activity / application is either a **intent action** and/or a **content provider Uri**.

Let's take an example: you have the IMDB id of a movie and you want to open up the detail page through the IMBD Android app. In that case you can do something like:

```
Intent detail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("imdb://<imdb_id>"));
if (context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(test, 0) != null) {
    startActivity(this, detail);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "IMDB not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

because the IMDB app provides a content provider with the prefix `imdb://`.

If the app provides an activity with a defined action filter, you just need to know this exact action like such:

```
startActivity(this, new Intent("target.app.action"));
```

Few years ago, there was a website that listed all open intents that you could use. It still exists but seems abandoned => http://www.openintents.org/

Comment: but that's for android. My app will be developed with the same code for example html5,jquery mobile, css etc.

Comment: @keithSpiteri Oh... Sorry, I miss the cross platform thing. If you will use phonegap,  my answer is still valid (for Android only of course) as you can write your own native code and embed that into your app. I cannot help for iOS, I never wrote app for this platform.

Comment: yep I did.. cross-platform app point number 1. I never wrote native code or did you mean (html)

Comment: I don't know why someone marked my question to -1 as  It is a genuine question